# What is currently the **best** and **secure** way to extract a certain text using jenkins in a pom.xml file

Tags: jenkins, pom.xml, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

What is currently the **best** and **secure** way to extract a certain text using jenkins in a pom.xml file. I have read many articles mentioning not to use readMavenPom because it's already depreciated. I would like to extract item in groupId, artifactId, version and name.

```
    <groupId>**LoveMyGroup**</groupId>
    <artifactId>**portal**</artifactId>
    <version>**0.0.1-SNAPSHOT**</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>**My first Project**</name>
    <description>My first Project ever</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
```